# How to get data from opened file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code where,

Worksheet: "Main" B3: what I am searching for in the file.
 worksheet "AX": where to search.

I want to search in another opened workbook beginning with the letters: ECL_

```
Sub FindandKopy()
Dim CellContents As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim loDeinWert As String
Dim sfirstaddress As String

loDeinWert = Worksheets("main").Range("B3").Value

Set rng = Worksheets("AX").Range("B:B").Find(loDeinWert)
If rng Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Data " & loDeinWert & " not found!"
Else
  sfirstaddress = rng.Address
  Do
    rng.EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) _
      .Offset(6, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll 
    Set rng = Worksheets("AX").Range("B:B").FindNext(rng)
  Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> sfirstaddress
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have You tried `GetObject` ?

Comment: Please redefine your question. See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). Point out where exactly you got stuck in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to find a workbook that is already opened you could loop through all workbooks and check each workbooks name:

```
Dim ECLWb As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb in Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "ECL_*" Then 
        Set ECLWb = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb

If ECLWb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "ECL_* not found."
    Exit Sub
Else
    'use that workbook like 
    ECLWb.Worksheets("AX")…
End If
```